# Uniqueness of Simple Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose the solution to the ODE $x'(t) = ax(t)$ is given as:

$$x(t) = ke^{at}$$

for any real number $k$.

Mow the claim is that there are no other solutions. To see this, let $u(t)$ be any solution and compute the derivative of $u(t)e^{-at}$:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(u(t)e^{-at}) = au(t)e^{-at} - au(t)e^{-at} = 0$$

this after simplifying the above expression. This establishes that $u(t)e^{-at}$ is a constant $k$ so $u(t) = ke^{at}$.

My question is where did the idea to compute the derivative of $u(t)e^{-at}$ come about? And how is it being used? From what I know of showing an object to be unique you would let two different iterations of the object be equal and then establish the equality.

Comment: [This might help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First-order_equation).

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. You know one solution, namely $e^{at}$, and you suppose you have another, $u(t)$. The hypothesis is that $u(t)$ has to be a multiple of $e^{at}$, so you divide the one by the other, and indeed get a constant. Hence, the hypothesis is proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you already know (or expect) the solution to be a multiple of $e^{at}$. If that's the case, then $u(t)e^{-at}$ should be constant, so its derivative should be zero. And that's exactly what the trick does.

Comment: Ah...that makes sense so in math notation I am in a situation where I would express it as $u(t) = ke^{at}$. ....Now maybe I'm thinking way too far out the box, but why would I "expect" the solution to be a multiple of $e^{at}$? When I think of different solution I am thinking that it would be a completely different expression to the original.

Comment: The exponential is a well-known function, that pops up fairly naturally (both logically and historically), and it equals its own derivative. Because of that it is reasonable to postulate exponentials as solutions of linear differential equations with constant coefficients. If you want a more "abstract" approach, you can postulate a solution to be a power series, put it into the equation and work out the coefficients, which will turn out to be those of the exponential.

Comment: Thank you for the added clarification. This makes me feel more settled about it.